# How to sort multiple element

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
switch($kk)
{ 
    case 1:
        $flag=true;
        if ($month) 
        {
            echo"<pre>";   
            echo $select->where('start_date between "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-01" and "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $this->daysInMonth($month, $year).'" and end_date between "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-01" and "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $this->daysInMonth($month, $year).'"' );

        } 
        $select->order('start_date ASC');       
        break;

    case 2:
        $flag=true;
        if ($month) 
        {
            echo $select->where('start_date < "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-01"  and end_date between "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-01" and "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $this->daysInMonth($month, $year).'"' );

        }
        $select->order('start_date ASC');
        break;

    case 3:
        $flag=true;
        if ($month) {
            echo $select->where('start_date between "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-01" and "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $this->daysInMonth($month, $year).'" and end_date > "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-'.$this->daysInMonth($month, $year).'"' );
        }
        $select->order('start_date ASC');
        break;

    case 4:
        $flag=true;
        if ($month) {
            echo $select->where('start_date < "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-01" and end_date > "' . $year . '-' . $month . '-'.$this->daysInMonth($month, $year).'"' );
        }
        $select->order('start_date ASC');
        break;
}
```

`$select->order('start_date ASC');` This statement sorts element. But it sorts according to result of query cases. I need one sort query to sort all cases result. How should I do?

Comment: each case sort seperatly, but i need after switch sort all element

Answer (score 0):

You have to come out of the switch{} statement, it only executes whats in the case. Even if you put that in the default: it won't work because it works individually with cases or default. I would create an entry after the switch statement.

Verify that your switch case executed then have another statement that does the sort to apply to all cases.